# jquery on change not firing in bs modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a script that needs to run in a bs modal.  I can run just the "    $("#SeedId").on("change", function () {..." part in a jsfiddle without the modal stuff, and it works fine.  So the modal opens and console.log function fires, but then the seedid on change function will not, even though it will if not in a modal.

On the view I have the script rendered on the bottom:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/mixSeed.js")
}
```

mixSeed.js is the last script rendered, after the jquery and unobtrusive ajax.

The code in the mixSeed.js is:

```
$(function () {
    var binUrl = $("#BinsUrl").val();

    $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal-container', function () {
        //cascading dropdown. Populate bin locations for given seed.

        console.log("modal is now open");

        $("#SeedId").on("change", function () {
            var seed = $(this).val();
            $("#BinId").empty();

            console.log("seedid is: " + seed);

            $.get({
                url: binUrl,
                data: { seedId: seed },
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                        $("#BinId").append($('<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>'));
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

$("#SeedId") is a select list, as is $("#BinId").  The "modal is now open" always shows in the console, but the "Seedid is" message does not.  A breakpoint anywhere in the 'on change' is not hit.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3wc894zt/

Comment: Works for me http://jsbin.com/decutadupa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: ur fiddle works https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/3wc894zt/1/

Comment: The fiddle was just to prove the code inside the shown.bs.modal was working.  I fixed it by changing 'shown' to 'loaded'

Answer (score 0):

I changed shown.bs.modal to loaded.bs.modal and it started working.